# Button width is symmetrical on pc but not symmetrical on android python/kivy

Tags: python, kivy, widget, resize, kivymd

*I created a custom Toggle Button, setting `size_hint_x`  to `None`  to put `width`. The button is perfect on pc but on android it is as if the width of the button had been reset.*

**MyWidget.kv:**

```
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<MyButton>:
    size_hint_x: None
    width: Window.width/3
    font_name: "path/to/font.ttf"
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_dark
    background_down: get_color_from_hex("#2e5871")
    font_color_normal: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    font_color_down: app.theme_cls.primary_light
    allow_no_selection: False
```

**MyWidget.py**

```
from kivymd.uix.behaviors.toggle_behavior import MDToggleButton
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

class MyButton(MDRectangleFlatButton, MDToggleButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.background_normal = 1, 1, 1, 1
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

**Location I'm using the button:**

```
MDRelativeLayout:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: dp(45)

    MyButton:
        text: "List 1"
        group: "list"
        pos_hint: {"top":1, "left":1}

    MyButton:
        text: "List 2"
        group: "list"
        pos_hint: {"top":1, "center_x":.5}

    MyButton:
        text: "List 3"
        group: "list"
        pos_hint: {"top":1, "right":1}
```

**Here is the app images**

[Application on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJlnu.png)

[Application on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y9EK.jpg)

Comment: Did you try setting `size_hint_x` to 1 ?

Comment: Changing `size_hint_x` really works, on android I got a desired size. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The issue was resolved by changing the `size_hint_x` instead of the `width`.*

**Obrigado @ApuCoder**